# Restarting socket connection does not succeed

Tags: sockets, serversocket, asyncsocket, socketexception

Below is the code for restarting the socket connection server,so when their is some disturbance its able to reconnect  but at some point or situations  its not able to reconnect/connect  what may be the issue in the  code issue  at below

```
/***   restarting the server by capturing the SIGHUP signal ***/

int isfirst;`enter code here`
char **command_args;

void sig_hangup(int signum)
{
    if ( isfirst )
    {
        isfirst = 0;
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent died\n");
    }`enter code here`
    else                /* Restart! */
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Restarting...\n");
        /*** Kill all existing child processes ***/
        execv(command_args[0], command_args);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not restart!!!\n");
        abort();
    }
}

void child(void)
{   struct sigaction act;

    bzero(&act, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_handler = sig_hangup;
    act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
/*  if ( sigaction(SIGHUP, &act, 0) != 0 )
        perror("Can't capture SIGHUP");*/
    for (;;)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[pid=%d] I'm still here\n", getpid());
        sleep(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}

int main(int count, char *strings[])
{
    isfirst = 1;
    command_args = strings;
    if ( fork() == 0 )
        child();
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'Not able to reconnect/connect' is not an adequate problem description. Try again.

Comment: Also, please make this code more readable - there are some 'enter code here' leftovers. It'd be nice if it was syntax-highlighted as well.

Comment: No the issue is 99% its able to reconnect but in some situations its not able to reconnect and i should manually do it. analysying is their any error in the code

Comment: is the execve'd process it not able to reconnect or the father process just can't restart it?